# Resilient uploader for Google Cloud Platform

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

Are there any open sources resilient file uploaders that work on Google Cloud Storage? This is what we've used for Amazon S3, which works great -- https://github.com/cinely/mule-uploader. We're looking for something that will have the following abilities:

- Resilient to shaky internet connections
- Works on huge files (100GB)
- Works entirely in-browser with real-time progress (not gsutil command line or other)

Do any open source uploaders support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One open source option that seems to have the above criteria is:

- https://github.com/QubitProducts/gcs-browser-upload

It is resumable and reads the file in chunks so progress can be shown on the front-end.